# Kernel Panic issue in setup_arch() function

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, arm, linux-device-driver

I am facing a Kernel Panic issue while booting an **armv7** board with `linux-3.0 kernel`. The Error message is as follows:
`Memory policy: ECC disabled, Data cache writealloc
<0>Kernel panic - not syncing: ERROR: Failed to allocate 0x1000 bytes below 0x0.`

I think this issue is related to some config in menuconfig but not able to get which one is exactly giving the problem. When I tried to trace the function which is causing this , I got the following call trace.

`paging_init -> early_alloc.clone.2 -> memblock_alloc -> memblock_alloc_base -> __memblock_alloc_base -> memblock_align_up -> memblock_find_base -> __memblock_alloc_base -> panic`.

**Boot parameters through uboot:**

`bootargs=console=ttyS1,115200n8 root=/dev/nfs ip=1.2.3.4 nfsroot=10.22.33.27:/tftpboot/arm/ rootwait rw`

Answer (score 2):

It looks like that your kernel is trying to load on the higher address than it is actually allocated. So you need to look into the DTS file (if using the device tree) or boot parameters which you are passing from the u-boot prompt.

You can check the memory allocation from kernel menuconfig, 
Kernel Features  ---> Memory split ---> 3G/1G user/kernel split.

Also please tell the processor on which you are facing this error.

P.S.: Assuming that LOADADDR for compiling the kernel image (uImage/bZimage) and DDR configuration is correct.

Comment: I am using `linux-3.0` which does not support `dts`. And the processor is `armv7`. I have checked the memory split and it is `3G/1G` as u specified. Should I change it? Boot parameters I have added in the question.

Comment: Oh so you are trying with NFS booting. I think 1GB memory is enough for kernel space. 
But your device IP (1.2.3.4 mentined in your boot args) is also not looking fine to me (both IPs should be in same domain).

Can you try to set the your boot args based on below example:

setenv ipaddr 10.0.0.2; setenv netmask 255.255.255.0; setenv serverip 10.0.0.1

tftpboot 0x12000000 uImage;tftpboot 0x18000000 myfile.dtb

setenv bootargs enable_wait_mode=off console=ttyS0,115200 rootwait root=/dev/nfs nfsroot=10.0.0.1:/home/nfs_folder/ ip=10.0.0.2 rw

Comment: There is no dtb file

Comment: NP. In that case you need to load the kernel image only. 

tftpboot <loadaddr> <kernel_image>

But make sure that your loadaddr should be correct.

Comment: The Linux start assembler should relocate to the proper address.  I don't think the 'loadaddr' matters except that there has to be memory there or u-boot will load stuff to some crazy locations (or not at all).